# Edit list of Resource

Tags: react-admin

I have this long descriptions in my React-admin :

[image: example]

I would like to set a substring on this field like this : `.substring(0, 50)} + "..."` but I don't know where to do this. Anyone know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `sx` prop:

```
<Datagrid>
  <TextField source="title" />
  <TextField source="description" sx={{
        maxWidth: '20em',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
  }} />
</Datagrid>
```

More details at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#sx